# proof of positive semi-definiteness of the precision matrix (inverse of the covariance matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance

I would like to know how to prove that the inverse of a covariance matrix $\Sigma^{-1}=\Omega$ is positive semi-definite too.

My second question can we prove that for any matrix $A\in\cal{M}_{nm}$ we have the determinant $|A^T~\Omega~A|\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Every covariance matrix is positive semidefinite. Hence every *invertible* covariance matrix is positive definite. Now, every positive definite matrix is unitarily diagonalisable. Therefore ...

For your second question, presumably the matrices are real. Consider the quantity $x^TA^T\Omega Ax$. Do you see that it is always nonnegative?

Comment: Actually, I am a grad student and my last course in algebra was in 2008. Anyways, I could answer this by considering the eignevalues of the inverse which are positive hence the positive definiteness..
Regarding the second question I think it's easy to prove that by doing the cholesky decomposition of $\Omega$ then we can prove that the prodcut is positive definite since it's of the form $(\cdot)^T(\cdot)$ which is nothing but the squared $L_2$ norm that is always positive..

Comment: @Bel Yes, that's a nice way to answer your question.