# inverse of a covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the inverse of a covariance matrix also guaranteed to be symmetric. A valid covariance matrix is symmetric PSD and all the matlab tests I have done seem to indicate that the inverse is also symmetric (Is it also PD?) but I wanted to confirm it.

Comment: Variants of this have been asked a lot here. Answer is YES on all your questions, see for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755116/proof-of-positive-semi-definiteness-of-the-precision-matrix-inverse-of-the-cova     and search this site.

Comment: @Luca,...and, for when the covariance matrix $C$ is invertible, you are wondering if

$$
(C^{-1})^T = (C^{T})^{-1} = (C)^{-1}\,?
$$

Comment: well, at the moment I only needed to know about the transpose to simplify some computations (completing the square) but sure yes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a covariance matrix I suppose we are working over the real field. So then since the matrix is symmetric it is orthogonally diagonalizable. So, all you have to do, to prove that the inverse is also symmetric is the following: suppose the matrix of interest is $S$, then write $S$ in terms of a product of the diagonal matrix it is similar to and the orthogonal matrix $P$ and its inverse $P^T$ consisting of eigenvectors. Then just write out $S^{-1}$ and $(S^{-1})^T$ in terms of these factors, manipulate, and see if they are the same. This is of course assuming the matrix is PD; if it has $0$ as eigenvalue it is not invertible.